# Difference between static variable declared inside a static block and outside a static block in java

Tags: java, static

1. What is the difference between a static variable declared outside a static block and a variable declared inside a static block? (considering the code segment)

A code segment is as follows:

```
class A{

    static int i = 10;      //line 1

    static { int i = 20;}   //line 2

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(A.i); //output is 10
    }
}
```

2.How to access variable 'i' in line 2?

Comment: Looks like homework, but regardless, how about showing us your thoughts on the answer.

Comment: The differences is that one has a wider scope than the other, that is all.

Comment: Why it doesn't give an error, because both are static and has the same name which is 'i' ?

Comment: @chathura2020 is this just copy-pasted out of your homework assignment? Lazy.

Comment: `static { }` does not declare static variables, it's actually a method that's allowed to be specified to initialize static.  As with any method, a variable declared in the static init method is local to that method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 static int i = 10;      //line 1
```

*here scope of variable `i` is at class level.You can access it form anywhere inside class.*

```
static { int i = 20;}   //line 2
```

*here scope of variable `i` is limited to the static block only(like in loop variable)*.You can not access it from outside block.

Comment: Correct, but would have been better to see OP post their own thoughts before answering

Answer (score 0):

In my opinions

"i" in Line 1 is a **global** variable,but in Line 2 it is **local**,that is to say you can't access variable out of it's scope(also this is the answer for question 2)

```
static {
    int i = 10;
    // this variable's scope only in static {},out of {},you can't access
    // so, if you want access a variable declared in a it's part,you must hold it's refer
    // but, if do this,why not declared it as a class instance member variable or static member variable(just like line 1)
    // generally,static code block is used in initial some class variable or do some prepare work when ClassLoader load it
}
```